# Rudeck: Using node environment variables, inside a scheduled job

Tags: rundeck

I have a scheduled job on rundeck (2.6.2).

This jobs run a script that needs an node environment variable available (like $HOME, $USER or $PWD. A custom one. ) for all user in the node/nodes.

I could use jobs options to solve this if I wanted trigger the job from API ( Or manually. Rundeck ask me for the option ) but is a scheduled job. I can't use *Options -> Default Value* because the jobs could run in nodes with different values for this environment variable.

There is any way to offers all / some **node** environment variables to rundeck to be used inside the **scheduled** jobs?

(I have thought in use *Options -> Allowed Values -> Remote URL* but is a mess. Too complicated to me requirement)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way in my case has been to customize `/etc/rundeck/profile` adding into it all the stuff I wanted.

Seems a pretty good solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to perform this by adding the following lines:

```
set -a
. /etc/environment
. /etc/profile
```

1) put those lines into the file: /etc/rundeck/profile

2) put those lines into a script step

Remark: I'm using only script steps in my rundeck and I'm always put this lines in the first line of the script step:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```